# Android Icon Keeps Defaulting Back

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ive imported a module into my project and im running into a conflict

Both the main AndroidManifest  and the module reference the same icon name for the android:icon setting

To resolve it i imported another icon and called it ic_launcher2 and referenced it as a mipmap and not a drawable.

When i change the name in the manifest file and build, it automatically changes back

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.scanlibrary.ScanActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Whatever i change it to, it always defaults back to the above, even if i use another draw able resource

Answer (score 0):

App icon files should all be named `ic_launcher` and of various [sizes](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/).

In the folder structure, there should be a folder to house each size variety of the icon, and as long as the `mipmap` references are defined currently, there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Changing drawable to mipmap, with a valid mipmap resource called ic_launcher simply changes back to drawable

Comment: @PowerMan2015 hmm, update your post with a screenshot of the file structure